# FFMpeg Converting a video to 8 bit BMP frames

Tags: bitmap, ffmpeg, 8-bit

I have been having trouble converting a video to 8 bit BMP frames. How to convert it using FFmpeg? or have suggestion software to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you just want one frame:

`ffmpeg -i <input> -vframes 1 -pix_fmt bgr8 -y output.bmp`

If you want lots of output frames:

`ffmpeg -i <input> -pix_fmt bgr8  yo%03d.bmp`

Comment: thank you :)
btw, how to converting back result of bitmaps into video?

Comment: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20video%20slideshow%20from%20images may help

Comment: how much will it fast ??